# Add white outline around a css circle on only one side

Tags: css, geometry

thanks in advance for reading.

I'm not sure how to explain my problem but I'll link some images first so you have an idea, afterwards I will explain myself further and add some code.

I have this: [What I have](http://gyazo.com/f4fb44e3e7426e2fa37f79f0dd6290a9)
What I want: [What I want](http://gyazo.com/b2a053a55a02289a61b9fa33b2f67d00)

I'll give the *CSS* for my circles and their container:

```
.circle-container {
    width: 68%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    background: url(img.jpg);
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;   
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-right: 100px;
}
.circle {
    float:left;
    height:100%;
    width:33%;
    border: #A93932 solid 4px;
    border-radius:50%;
    background-color:rgb(227,5,19);
    background-color:rgba(227,5,19,0.8);
}
```

Obviously the above *CSS* does not make it a circle, look at the following script for how I did that:

Script to make the circles responsive:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    $('.circle').css('height', $('.circle').width());
    if($('.circle').height() > $(window).height())
    {
        $('.circle').css('height', $(window).height());
        $('.circle').css('width', $(window).height());
    }
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.circle').css('height', $('.circle').width());
    if($('.circle').height() > $(window).height())
    {
        $('.circle').css('height', $(window).height());
        $('.circle').css('width', $(window).height());
    }
});
```

If there is any more *CSS* or maybe HTML needed, i would like to hear it!

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe this one will help you more http://jsfiddle.net/csdtesting/kn6bsy2y/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To your `.circle-container`, adjust the `border-radius` property

So, your code should look like this:

```
.circle-container{
  border-top-left-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
}
```

Hope it helps :)

**EDIT:** Here's a [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rdesai/ofdea86L/)

Comment: Haha, how didn't I think of that.. Thanks sir!

Comment: Good try but is not working with background image like that .http://jsfiddle.net/csdtesting/ofdea86L/1/ . I am working in this too,its hard. Just saying.

Comment: That's true, getting it to line up perfectly is quite a struggle. If you have any idea's post them!

Answer (score 0):

I tried to find a solution to tha by using pseudo -elements,but using two times the `background-image` property.

Looks like:

[image]

An example of this would be:

```css
body {
  background: url(http://geocarrefour.revues.org/docannexe/image/842/img-1-small580.png) no-repeat;
}
.inner-bg {
  background: url(http://geocarrefour.revues.org/docannexe/image/842/img-1-small580.png) no-repeat;
  height: 425px;
  width: 380px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
div.wrap {
  height: 425px;
  width: 400px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
div.inner {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
  height: 405px;
  width: 380px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: auto;
}
div.inner:after {
  content: "";
  background: white;
  opacity: 0.5;
  top: 20px;
  left: 15px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 250px;
  right: 0;
  height: 425px;
  width: 380px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5;
}
div.wrap:after {
  content: "";
  background: red;
  height: 425px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 180px;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="inner-bg"></div>
  </div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This indeed is a good solution, I'm currently trying to make a div with negative border radius, I've got this: http://jsfiddle.net/EjE7c/2294/ read the text in the div. Thanks for helping me with this!